# How to wake up another Android app?

Tags: android

I'd like to write a watchdog app that watches over another app and wakes it up if it's not alive.

Is there a way to wake up another app **without** specific integration? perhaps waking up some service on the other app?

** By waking up I mean the other app starts running but not showing any UI explicitly. For example, a voice recorder might wake up and work in the background. It's main view should NOT be shown.

Comment: You could take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html
. Not sure if this is what your looking for, your question is pretty broad.

Comment: @user1281750, why do you think an aidl file would help here?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the fact "another applicaiton", "specific integration" and other things, you question is too broad to give a proper solution

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: Regarding your example an aidl could be used - a note from reference: Using AIDL is necessary only if you allow clients from different applications to access your service for IPC and want to handle multithreading in your service. If you don't need the multitreading part, just go with services.

Comment: Muthithreading is NOT needed here so I guess aidl is NOT needed here as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an intent with action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER
2. Get the PackageManager from the current context using context.getPackageManager
3. packageManager.queryIntentActivity(<*intent*>, 0) where intent has category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN or packageManager.resolveActivity(<*intent*>, 0) to get the first activity with main/launcher
4. Get the ActivityInfo you're interested in
5. From the ActivityInfo, get the packageName and name
6. Finally, create another intent with with category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN, componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name) and setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
7. Finally, context.startActivity(newIntent)

Or you can use :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This will open the activity and probably some kind of view. I'd like the app to be woken up without any UI interference.

Comment: The other app might have a service.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine give a try

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("package_name");//for e.g.(com.android.sms)//but this app must be in your device

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This will open the activity and probably some kind of view. I'd like the app to be woken up without any UI interference.

Comment: then you must know other apps Service name

and then you can use this


private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
           //here you can start service
        }
    }
    return false;
}

where com.example.MyService is service name of application which you want to woken up,
hope this works, merry chrismas :)

Comment: So how can the service be woken up?

Comment: using startService("com.example.MyService").

Comment: assume my app name is AppA now i want to wake up another app which is AppB
using above method i came to know that in AppB i have a service "Com.AppB.MyService"

now from AppA there should be your requirement how and when you want to wake up another app, so now simple at that situation you can call above method, and check in DDMS your woken up package name should be there.

Comment: eg. startService("Com.AppB.MyService").

Comment: if you want to do wake up any app on any event in that case you can use broadcast receiver for example if you want to wake up any app which has service(an app which doesn't have service can not be woken up in the way you need) and you want to start another process i.e. service then for exm. you want to do this when your data connection is lost then you should create an receiver and should give permission in manifest to receive when data connectivity changes then you will require CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE permission.

Comment: but if you do not if an application doesn't have service and you want to start in back ground then you should try to check if that app has an receiver and if it has then you should simply broadcast that receiver and even if app doesn't have an receiver then you should find out the activity name start that activity and once you start just remove it from backstack, i am not sure but it might have a little UI issue, but this should work, just give a try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track an app which is running in background with out user interference (in this case i am assuming that it is using services in background)we can track it by the following code.

```
private boolean isOurServiceRunning(Context context) {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> listinfo = manager
                    .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> iterator = listinfo
                    .iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info = iterator.next();


                if (info.service
                        .getClassName()
                        .equals("<your service with fullpackage name>"))

                    return true;

            }
            return false;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I wake it up?

Comment: you can use broadcast receivers for that.

Comment: As I understand things, there's no connection between a broadcast receivers and services.

Comment: lets us assume our targeted application contains a service, and we can find at any time whether the service is running or not by above mentioned code. If it gives false then we can explicitly launch the application by calling                                              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("<package name>","<packagename>.<MainActivity">);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: This will open the activity and probably some kind of view. I'd like the app to be woken up without any UI interference.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to revoke another application from your code.

```
 Intent intent;
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            try {
                intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mycompany.myapp");
                if (intent == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: This will open the activity and probably some kind of view. I'd like the app to be woken up without any UI interference.

Comment: if you want that app should show any ui then the destination app should not have action-main and category-launcher in the manifest file